# Python 3 failed error on starting Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda 2019.03 on my 32 bit Windows 7(not updated since ages!!) and it is showing Python 3 failed to start on launching a Jupyter Notebook via Anaconda.. pls help..Thanks!

Comment: can you share the full errror log here?

Comment: It’s showing Python 3 failed.... can’t establish the connection to a terminal

Answer (score 0):

I use anaconda in windows 10pro and I don't face any problem. So  I think, it don't matching between Windows7 and Anaconda 2019.03.
You can use online ternimal and below the link of **Cocalc**

Comment: Thanks Imdadul... can I load csv files using Cocalc